# ImageView widget rotator

Tags: android, rotation, widget, imageview, banner

I'm developing an android widget application that displays some images in a loop. This widget simulates a website image banner rotator.

I'm using a ScheduledExecutorService to execute the task that changes the current image by the next one.

All images should change each 2 or 3 seconds but Android seems to dislike this behaviour stopping the task in a few minutes.

I have tried to use an animated gif but it shows it as a static image.

Can anyone give me any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use android's Alarm Manager mechanism instead of ScheduledExecutorService. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

For using a gif you can use WebView or Movie class (like explain in this tutorial).

http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-how-to-use-animated-gif/

and for doing a banner rotator go at this link [android ad banner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011134/android-ad-banner)