# How can i put a Banner Rotator?

Tags: android, banner, rotator

i want put in the top of my app 1 banner rotator. I found this answer, but i get like 30 errors D:   (i am newbie)

[android ad banner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011134/android-ad-banner)

If someone can do work the code, or put other code, i will be grateful.

Comment: that is a good code if what you want is a banner rotating on swap. If you need an auto rotator, you need to extend it. anyways, you should use it, and try to fix every error, step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of Crossfading Two Views, in the android training website, with the full code, than can be useful to you, if you can adapt it.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html

You can also follow some other approaches, like  a extending a [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html)

Anyways if you cannot use the code of the post you are linking, probably you need a few more of reading before, since every solution will require the same level or undestanding (and a full copy/paste is never  a solution)